# wordpress display menu items vertically

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to show the sub-submenus of my website under their parent menu node, much like the [oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/index.html). I installed a theme named [Oracle](http://www.fabthemes.com/oracle/), which looks good. My requirement now is to show the sub sub menus directly under their parents (in columns if possible), and not while hovering on their parents. I just need some indications on where I could tweak the code for creating menus and sub menus, in order to change the resulting HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit the php files containing the menu and extend it by the sub-sub-menus if it does not yet. The elements get displayed during `:hover`. These styles are about at line 455 in the `style.css`. To learn more about where to start editing through the web inspector in chrome and firefox. They both display the line number next to the styles of the element that are inspected. Good luck!